# Sorting rows at value with multiple hierarchical levels

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, hierarchy

I have a list of hierarchical product prices with their prices already aggregated. The hierarchical levels are **cluster**, **store** and **shelf**.

[image: Unsorted products prices]

I would like to sort these product prices hierarchically. Each level needs to be sorted. Here is an example of the expected result:

[image: Expected result]

Right now, I can sort prices at shelf level but not at store or cluster level yet:

```
SELECT cluster_id, store_id, shelf_id, price FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT p.*,
            ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
                ORDER BY
                cluster_id ASC NULLS FIRST,
                store_id ASC NULLS FIRST,
                price DESC
            ) AS rn
        FROM (SELECT * FROM products) p
    )
)
ORDER BY rn;
```

My actual result is:

[image: My actual result]

I'm using Oracle Database 12c.

**Sample data**

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    cluster_id     VARCHAR2(30),
    store_id       VARCHAR2(30),
    shelf_id       VARCHAR2(40),
    price          NUMBER(*,2)
);

INSERT INTO products VALUES ('10','230',NULL,120);
INSERT INTO products VALUES (NULL,NULL,NULL,500);
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('10','230','967',40);
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('10',NULL,NULL,300);
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('50','430','863',50);
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('50','170',NULL,70);
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('10','500','783',100);
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('50','170','798',20);
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('50','480',NULL,80);
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('50','430',NULL,50);
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('10','500',NULL,180);
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('50','480','486',60);
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('10','230','296',80);
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('50',NULL,NULL,200);
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('10','500','344',80);
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('50','480','234',20);
INSERT INTO products VALUES ('50','170','368',50);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ordering method gives desired output:

```
select p.*
  from products p
  order by 
       sum(case when store_id is not null and shelf_id is not null then price end) 
           over (partition by cluster_id) desc,
       sum(case when store_id is not null and shelf_id is not null then price end) 
           over (partition by cluster_id, store_id) desc,
       case when shelf_id is null then 1 end, price desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
with t as (
  select cluster_id
  , store_id
  , shelf_id
  , price
  , row_number() over (partition by cluster_id order by price desc) cluster_sort
  , row_number() over (partition by cluster_id, store_id order by price desc) store_sort
  , row_number() over (partition by cluster_id, store_id, shelf_id order by price desc) shelf_sort
)
select cluster_id
, store_id
, shelf_id
, price
from t
order by cluster_sort
, store_sort
, shelf_sort
;
```

Comment: Your query doesn't works, it sort all the cluster by price, then all the couple cluster/store by price etc...